# Removing non-installed entries from Windows 10 start menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I just got a laptop with Windows 10 Home, pre-installed by Lenovo, and I noticed the following entries in my start menu (notice in particular that Candy Crush, Disney and Dolby have no icons):

[image: Windows 10 entries showing non-installed programs]

I'd like to remove them, but right-clicking on them only shows "Pin to Start". They are not listed in the Apps & features, so I cannot uninstall them.

I tried looking for information about how to remove them from that list, but because Candy Crush actually comes installed in many computers, the proposed solutions do not apply to my problem.

Is there a way to remove these non-installed apps from the list? Otherwise, how are they called?

**Edit**: sorry for the non-question, during the night Windows Update did something, and now the entries are gone. Unfortunately I cannot even reproduce the previous state to try the suggested answers.

Comment: Do you know that they don’t exist? What happens when you click the entry in the start menu? Do you get an error? What is the error?

Comment: I get an uninstall option when I right click on Candy Crush Soda Saga.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP claims it is no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to clean up the list, they are stored in 
"\programdata\Microsoft\windows\start menu\programs". Just go there and remove the entries.  note that programdata is a hidden folder so  you will have to unhide it first.

Comment: That is useful to know! Unfortunately, as I just mentioned, Windows Update changed something overnight so I don't see those entries anymore, not even in the mentioned folder. At least it confirms they were not installed.

Comment: @Larryc Those apps are from Windows Store. They don't save any shortcuts (.lnk files) in the folder that you've mentioned.